# Meteor.js loginWithGoogle does nothing

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am working on my first Meteor app that uses OAuth for login.  Prior to this, all of my projects have used only the accounts-password portions.

I have a simple login for with a button to login via Google:

```
<template name="login">
  <form id="login" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <button id="signin" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    <hr />
    Or:<br />
    <button id="loginWithFacebook">Login with Facebook</button>
    <button id="loginWithGoogle">Login with Google</button>
    <button id="loginWithTwitter">Login with Twitter</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

I then have a event handler to capture the button click and call the loginWithGoogle:

```
...
  "click #loginWithGoogle": function(e, t){
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
      requestPermissions: [],
      loginStyle: "popup"
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        // TODO Need to do something here with the error...
        console.log('Error: ', err);
      } else {
        Router.go('home');
      }
    });
  }
...
```

On the server I setup OAuth for Google like thus:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "google"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "google",
  clientId: "000000000000000",
  loginStyle: "popup",
  secret: "000000000"
});

Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  console.log('Creating user: ' + user.username);
  return user;
});
```

And in my route I have this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // Initialize the loading template before hand
    Router.onBeforeAction('loading');

    // Map the routes
    Router.map(function() {
        // Homepage
        this.route('home', {
            path: '/',
            onBeforeAction: function() {
              if (!Meteor.user()) {
                console.log('User is not logged in. Displaying login form.');
                Router.go('login');
              } else {
                console.log('User is already logged in:', Meteor.user());
              }
            }
        });

        // Login page
        this.route('login', {
            path: '/login'
        });
    });
}
```

So, I get the console log in the browser saying `User is not logged in. Displaying login form.`, and when I click the **Login with Google** button I get the popup asking which Google account I want to use, then the confirmation page.  But when I click the Accept button I get nothing.  The `Accounts.onCreateUser()` doesn't seem to run, nor does the callback code on the `loginWithGoogle()`.  How do I get this configured correctly so that the callback runs, and ultimately I am re-directed back to my homepage?

Comment: Try deploying your project on meteor.com then check if the login is working you will at least be fixed if it's a matter of callback from google/server or your code.

Comment: Do you know if I have to handle the redirect URL, or is that handled as part of the accounts-google package?

Comment: I never tried with google+ but I had the problem with FB where serving to the port 3000 was problematic. This is why I recommend trying on the official meteor.com site where everything is supposed to work out of the box (of course you need to give the right clientId and secret). The package will not redirect (route) anything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onCreateUser` doesn't work because you don't have username specified.

Try using

```
 if(user.services.google)
       user.username = user.services.google.name
```

And by the way, why won't you use `{{>loginButtons}}`?

Comment: As I said, this is my first attempt at a more complicated login process, so I wasn't aware of `{{>loginButtons}}`, or at least it didn't trigger in my mind when I was putting together a basic login page.  I will definitely switch to that, however.  I will also try your suggestion on changing the `onCreateUser` and see if that works as soon as I can.

Comment: The problem seemed to be a combination of not using the `{{loginButtons}}` and not printing the user correct.  Thanks for pointing me in the correct location.